# How to set initial weights in deeplabcut?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, pose-estimation, video-tracking

I am trying to train resnet50 on the horse-10 dataset. but I am facing an issue with determining the initial weights. I've looked it up, and the answer was to basically include the path of a snapshot, but I can’t find any snapshots in the horse-10 project folder and it is very confusing because I am an absolute beginner, and I don’t know how to obtain a snapshot for the initial weights.